# Fixed Effects in a latent variable framework using lavaan

Tags: r, fixed-effects-model, lavaan

I am just now familiarising myself with the literature on Fixed Effect Models. I was wondering if anyone had any references or could confirm that fixed effect models can be used in a latent variable framework.

I have a straightforward model with approximately 2000 individuals nested in 8 groups. I am primarily interested in the individual-level relationships. The number of clusters is also too small for a hierarchical model.

I have created the following syntax with lavaan, in R. Assuming x = predictor, y = dv, m1 = variable, m2 = variable, cov = individual-level covariates and group = group dummies(All continuous, except some of the covariates and of course the group dummies)

```
model <-'

#latent variable
x =~ x_a + x_b + x_c
m1 =~ m1_a + m1_b + m1_c + m1_d
m2 =~ m2_a + m2_b + m2_c
y =~ y_a + y_b + y_c

#structural model
m1 ~  x + cov_ind1 + cov_ind2 + cov_ind3 + cov_ind4 + group1 + group2 + group3 + group4 + group5 + group6 + group7
m2 ~  x + cov_ind1 + cov_ind2 + cov_ind3 + cov_ind4 + group1 + group2 + group3 + group4 + group5 + group6 + group7
y ~ x + m1 + m2 + cov_ind1 + cov_ind2 + cov_ind3 + cov_ind4 + group1 + group2 + group3 + group4 + group5 + group6 + group7

#covariance
m1  ~~  m2

'
```

I'd be glad for any comment on whether this looks correct.